# How to find Distinct in more than one column in LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a LINQ statement that returns many columns. I need to find distinct of unique combination of two columns. What is the best way to do this.

```
var productAttributeQuery =
                from pa in ctx.exch_productattributeSet
                join pp in ctx.exch_parentproductSet
                    on pa.exch_ParentProductId.Id equals pp.Id
                join ep in ctx.exch_exchangeproductSet
                    on pp.exch_parentproductId equals ep.exch_ParentProductId.Id
                where pa.exch_EffBeginDate <= effectiveDateForBeginCompare
                      && pa.exch_EffEndDate >= effectiveDateForEndCompare
                      && pa.statuscode == StusCodeEnum.Active
                where pp.exch_EffBeginDate <= effectiveDateForBeginCompare
                      && pp.exch_EffEndDate >= effectiveDateForEndCompare
                      && pp.statuscode == StatusCodeEnum.Active
                where ep.statuscode == StatusCodeEnum.Active
                select new ProductAttributeDto
                {
                    ParentProductId = pa.exch_ParentProductId.Id, 
                    AttributeId = pa.exch_AttributeId.Id, 
                    AttributeValue = pa.exch_Value, 
                    AttributeRawValue = pa.exch_RawValue 
                };
            return productAttributeQuery.ToList();
```

I want to get Distinct combination of ParentProductId  and AttributeId  from this list

Answer (score 2):

You can group by anonymous type and select keys (they will be distinct)

```
var query = from p in productAttributeQuery
            group p by new {
               p.ParentProductId,
               p.AttributeId
            } into g
            select g.Key;
```

You can use same approach with you original query if you want to get distinct pairs on server side.

---

Another approach - project results into pairs and get distinct from them:

```
var query = productAttributeQuery
              .Select(p => new { p.ParentProductId, p.AttributeId })
              .Distinct();
```

Comment: @SofiaKhwaja instead of selecting new ProductAttributeDto you can select anonymous object with two required fields. Then call `Distinct()`.

Comment: Thanks for the new approach. I a running the query now . The issue I am facing when adding the result to a dictionary as                             var productAttributeDtoDictionary = productAttributeDtoList.ToDictionary(a => new Tuple<Guid, Guid>(a.ParentProductId, a.AttributeId), rec => new AttributeDto()
                {
                    Value = rec.AttributeValue,
                    RawValue = rec.AttributeRawValue
                }
                );        I get error Item has already been added to the dictionary, although it seems that distinct count is the same as  non dist count

Comment: The new query is giving me error The result selector of the 'Join' operation must return an anonymous type of two properties. Thanks for your advice.